# Make $dom = $html->load(file_get_contents($nextLink)) wait for website to load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

I have a HTML SIMPLE DOM PARSER program...

My problem is:

I'm trying to get the product links on different pages.

The links on the first page, collects no problem.

The big problem comes when I try to access the second page. There is an event that launches the product without changing the url, adding **#/page-2 ... 3 ... 4** according to the page.

The problem is that the program is unable to walk toward the second page. It is always in the first, repeating the links on this.

There a way to make the program move to the second page?

This is the code I use:

I put example url, but i use $nextLink to loop for the pages.

Thanks^^

```
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom = $html->load(file_get_contents(http://www.perfumeriasabina.com/es/29-perfumeria-sabina-online#/page-2));
        if (!empty($dom))
        {
            $dom->find('a');
        }   
     $productos = $html->find('.product_img_link');
     foreach($productos as $producto) 
     {
       $enlaces = $producto->href; 
       echo $enlaces . "<br/>";
     }
```

Comment: It's loading that with AJAX, so you need to figure out what the request is that's getting made and make it in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small research on that website, just append :

```
?p=2
```

To the url, according to the page number you want to to download, So your URL will look like :

```
http://www.perfumeriasabina.com/es/29-perfumeria-sabina-online?p=2
```

Comment: Jur, It's true.
Another time I put ?/p=page did not work and discarded.
But it works! Many thanks!